# Displaying progress bar for a webview in fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, progress-bar

I am trying to display a progress bar before the webpage appears or loads.I have declared the progressbar in onCreateView method of PlanetFragment which extends fragment I have removed the hearder of the webpage. But the progressbar doesn't appear whatsoever code I write. Please help

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet,
                container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
                getActivity().getPackageName());

        final WebView webview = ((WebView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.image));

        final ProgressBar progressbar = ((ProgressBar) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.progressbar));





        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final PlanetFragment activity = this;


        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('icon-anon')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('search')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_ad')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('cse_x')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_search')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_ad')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('wh_ad')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('footer_random_button')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('mw-mf-page-left')[0].style.display=\"none\";");
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('mw-mf-viewport')[0].style.display=\"none\";");

                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl(planet);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

This is my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. I have not tested it(dont have editor right now). The solution is hiding the webview and showing it at appropriate times.

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           //you might need this
           view.bringToFront();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,  Bitmap favicon) {
           view.setVisibility(View.GONE);//hide the webview that will display your dialog
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. I was not making the view invisible due to which progressbar was not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `ProgressBar` it's "below" the WebView in your xml (meaning that the first widget declared in xml will be the one at the deepest level, widgets are stacked).

Try to put the ProgressBar below in the xml and hide it when neccessary, like shown below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <WebView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressbar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently the `WebView` stays in front of your `ProgressBar`

Comment: Glad I could help. Use the one that's most natural to you :) Cheers